# How did the Declaration of Independence end up in the United States?

Tags: united-states, american-revolution

From what I understand the Declaration of Independence was largely disregarded by the English leaders. So, why did it not just get lost in mounds of paperwork like happens to unimportant documents today? Also, how did the original end up back in the states? Did we just ask them: "Hi, you know that treasonous document we sent you? Can we have it back to put on display for all posterity?"

P.S. I am assuming that we have the original in our  possession and that we sent the original to the king.

Comment: Voting to close because this seems fully answered by a Wikipedia article that specifically addresses the issue: [Physical history of the United States Declaration of Independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_history_of_the_United_States_Declaration_of_Independence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one original copy. After the Declaration of Independence was drafted multiple "fair copies" were made unsigned, Some of these were sent to printers to be printed throughout the colonies. Sometime later a fair copy was made and adopted by the Continental Congress, most of whose members then signed it. This copy is known as the "engrossed" copy.

The Declaration was never sent by the Congress to King George of England. He found out about it when printed broadsheets containing the text arrived with the news from the colonies. These were first printed in Belfast in August of 1776 and carried from there to London immediately afterwards.

(I should probably qualify the above by stating that King George found out about it "publicly" in August. Of course, the British had many spies and sympathizers in the Congress and they undoubtedly knew of the whole progress of the Declaration which began in the spring of 1776. So, secretely George would have known of the text almost as soon as it was produced plus the two weeks to carry it to England. Publicly the text first appeared in Ireland and Scotland, not England, probably because of censorship.)

Comment: Really good answer Tyler. Can you provide links for any of it?